# Angular Upload File and Additional Data ASP WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to upload a form with some text fields and a file to my WebAPI. Currently I always get a 415 error (a breakpoint in the ASP controller doesn't gets hit). My code looks like this:

**Angular Service**

```
// 'Upload' is from ng-file-upload
function applicationService(settings, $http, Upload) {
  var createCustomApplication = function(application) {
    var url = settings.baseUrl + '/api/applications/custom';

    var data = new FormData();
    angular.forEach(application, function (value, key) {
      data.append(key, value);
    });

    return Upload.upload({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      method: 'POST'
    });
  };

  return {
    createCustomApplication: createCustomApplication
  }
}
```

**WebAPI controller**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ApplicationModel))]
[HttpPost, Route("api/applications/custom")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateCustomApplication([FromBody]ApplicationModel application)
{
   var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
   return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include a form with files as parameter to an action it is necessary to add a custom media formatter. [Fortunately someone already created a Nuget-package for this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MultipartDataMediaFormatter/). Configuration is easy. Install the package and add a line to your WebApiConfig-file.

This package allows you to use a `HttpFile`-object which captures your file either directly as a parameter or inside a model. [From the docs](https://github.com/iLexDev/ASP.NET-WebApi-MultipartDataMediaFormatter):

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostFileBindRawFormData(MultipartDataMediaFormatter.Infrastructure.FormData formData)
{
    HttpFile file;
    formData.TryGetValue(<key>, out file);
}
```

or

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public DateTime? BirthDate {get; set;}
    public HttpFile AvatarImage {get; set;}
    public List<HttpFile> Attachments {get; set;}
    public List<PersonModel> ConnectedPersons {get; set;}
}

//api controller example
[HttpPost]
public void PostPerson(PersonModel model)
{
    //do something with the model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. 
You should add the content type in your POST request.

```
headers: {
     'Content-Type': undefined
},
```

Comment: After adding the header I get the same error message. When I inspect my headers from my request in the devtools, nothing has changed (the header value is still `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryVgMJf1g7g2DX9LUd`)

Answer (score 0):

You're code looks very similar to what I use. Perhaps the issue is to do with the multipart/form-data header value. I'm not experienced enough to say what is wrong in your implementation, but perhaps try this alternate async await approach.

```
[Route("api/applications/custom")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
{
    MultipartMemoryStreamProvider memoryStreamProvider;
    try
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        memoryStreamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, string.Format("An error has occured while uploading your file. Error details: '{0}'", e.Message));    
    }

    // do something with your file...

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

}
```

Here is my JS code. I also use promises instead of what ever is returned (if anything) from the Upload function.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
        $scope.upload($scope.file);
    }
};

$scope.upload = function(file) {

    Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/applications/custom',
        data: { file: file }
    }).then(function(response) {
        // report the success to the user
    }, function(response) {
        // report the error to the user
    }, function(evt) {
        // report the progress of the upload to the user
        $scope.uploadProgress = evt.loaded / evt.total;
    });
};
```

I used the following article as a basis for my solution: http://monox.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/233/Async-upload-using-angular-file-upload-directive-and-net-WebAPI-service/

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The `memoryStreamProvider` is null.

Comment: Ah, but the WebAPI action is being hit now. That's more than you had before, right?

Comment: Yes, it seems when I remove the parameter the action gets hit.

Comment: I assume the additional ","  in your upload object isn't causing the issue. Worth cleaning it up regardless. This one: method: 'POST',

Comment: Does your Upload actually return something? I use the promise notation to handle errors and successes. I'll post my js in my answer in case it gives you a clue.

Comment: Yes it returns just fine (either the error or the response I return).